# Can i have two wordpress website folders, different databases and different prefixes on XAMPP?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have WordPress installed locally on XAMPP and I decided to create a new folder and perform WordPress installation all over again in that folder.

Note that I already have another WordPress installation for a different website. The problem is I keep getting errors when I want to install a plugin or a theme on the new website. I assume it is because I have another WordPress installation on the same XAMPP installation. Are my assumptions correct?

Also, note that the two websites have a different database.

Comment: yes you can, what prevent you to have many wordpress installed on the xampp?pls give a try, it works

Comment: I already have it installed but i keep getting a memory error anytime i tried to install a plugin. I've tried increasing the size in the php.ini file but it doesn't fix the problem